# Open url with Process.Start some times throws "The wait operation timed out"

Tags: c#, wpf, url, process.start

I'm devoloping WPF application. I use the following code to open some link in browser.

```
string link = "https://www.somelink.com";
Uri myUri;
if (Uri.TryCreate(link, UriKind.Absolute, out myUri))
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(myUri.AbsoluteUri));
}
```

The problem is that i get some crash report and i can't find solution for this.
Following is the crash log:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's taking too long to get a response from the server. It's more likely a hardware problem than a software one.

Comment: It is a desktop app. I just want to open url and don't wait for result. I don't need result or any other kind of info.